# JQuery doesn't work unless I refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to fadeIn a Circle in my Rails 4 app and it only works when I refresh the page. This is my JQuery so far

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".circle-div").hide().fadeIn(2000); 
  })
```

I tried using doing

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    location.reload($(".circle-div").hide().fadeIn(2000)); 
  })
```

And it just reloads all my pages non stop. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you really want to do

Comment: Is everything else loaded when the page initially loads (without the refresh) eg scripts, stylesheets, etc?

Comment: Now try to reproduce issue on jsfiddle

Comment: Definitely don't go with a `page reload` solution. If you try other things, like `$("div").fadeOut()` or `$("body").fadeOut()`, do these run as expected?

Comment: @JohnRooney Yeah, everything works... It only works on refresh. All I want is it to work when I load the page.

Comment: So those don't work when the page initially loads? So this problem is not isolated to the mentioned div fading in--but it pertains to all jQuery on the page? It doesn't sound like jQuery (or your script) are being included in your page appropriately.

Comment: @JohnRooney Lol! Thanks John. That really narrows it down.

Comment: Based on @JohnRooney comment add a console.log() to the document ready handler and see if you get output to the console. If so, jQuery has run and there is some other issue. I'd suggest initially hiding the class with css, then invoking jQuery on it when the page loads.

Comment: Well knowing if you're actually loading jQuery is kind of important, and if it's not being loaded, would be the reason it's not working.

Comment: @JohnRooney Yes your right, but since it is loading that hints it's working ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circle-div").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
});
```